# Is there any way to stop PHP evaluating the two strings "1" and "1.0" as the same?

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a way to stop it evaluating two strings "1" and "1.0" as the same? The code below illustrates what I'm talking about:

```
<?php
    $str1 = "1";
    $str2 = "1.0";

    if($str1==$str2){
      echo "equal";
    }else{
      echo "not equal";
    }
?>
```

The problem for me is that I'm trying to check whether a user has changed a value when they submit it back to the server. At the moment if a user changes the value from "1" to "1.0" it should pick up the fact that they've changed the record and allow them to save it to the database - however because PHP evaluates them both as numbers when comparing them it thinks the user has made no changes and doesn't allow them to save it.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you used `===`?

Comment: @GrantThomas implying...

Comment: @Nick Leave it, don't feed the troll :)

Comment: @Nick That I would only wish PHP on my worst enemy.

Comment: @Jack Now, mine was an observation, yours is just mean. (:

Comment: @GrantThomas i'm interested, what do you hate about it. and what would you consider a superior server side language?

Comment: @Nick As if this (and all you can guess that behaves in ways _like_ this) isn't enough? [PHP: A Fractal of Bad Design](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) comes to mind. Yet, this 'troll' will take a step back from, and won't feed others by, suggesting alternatives: there are many, _any_.

Comment: @Nick see, I told you to leave it :) that fractal page is their favourite vehicle of misplaced opinion.

Comment: @Jack There are many, many other objective analyses, too. I mean, any thinking person can see the problems. I fully understand the utility of things, as do others - regardless of how much one _likes_ it or not (e.g. "_it's not nice, but it's a working solution!_") - but to protect it in the way a father would an ugly child does no favours for anybody (including the propagation of misconceptions).

Comment: http://www.phpsadness.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use

```
===
```

operator.

Comment: Wow what a noob mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Cheers Happy Coding..Mark answer as solved. :)

Answer (score 6):

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then **each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically**. [...]. **The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !==** as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Therefore the `==` operator makes a number conversion that leads `1` to be *equal* to `1.0`. If you use the `===` operator instead, each character of the string it compared to the other corresponding character of the string making a char-by-char comparison leading `"1"` and `"1.0"` to be two different strings, hence evaluating to false.

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to avoid the issue use

```
===
```

instead of

```
==
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strictly compare strings, use [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/strcmp):

```
if (strcmp($str1, $str2) == 0) {
    // they're the same
}
```

Granted, this is more verbose, but the alternative of using `===` has been well discussed already.